# How to create sub account in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, roles, privileges

after logging in with the account system
I created an oracle account in this way

```
CREATE USER ExampleAdmin IDENTIFIED by oracle 
DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS TEMPORARY 

TABLESPACE TEMP QUOTA 24M ON USERS PROFILE DEFAULT;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO ExampleAdmin;
```

and after logging in with the new account, I created the structure of my database with the related tables, views, triggers, procedures and etc.

now i'm trying to create a sub account that has the possibility to access only some created tables and i tried like this:

```
CREATE ROLE Bar;
GRANT CONNECT, CREATE SESSION TO Bar;
GRANT SELECT ON TableExample1 TO Bar;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON TableExample2 TO Bar;
CREATE USER BAR1 IDENTIFIED BY bar;
GRANT Bar TO BAR1;
```

and it gave me no error in the compilation.
But when I try a select from table TableExample1, it tells me that the table does not exist.
Where am I wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Did you add schema? `select * from ExampleAdmin.TableExample1`

Comment: THANKS
I didn't know it was necessary to specify the parent account before performing an operation ... sorry.
Thanks!

Comment: You can also create a synonym (either a public one, or a private one in Bar's schema) if you don't want to always specify the owning schema.

Comment: @kfinity ok i will try... maybe this would be great!